# When I delete an element from an array fetched using a service, where is it getting deleted?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm doing some experiments with angular in order to learn.

I have this file called instock.ts. Inside I created this object array:

```
export let inStock: Instocktype[] = [
    { name: 'saw', price: 3, amount: 2, discount: 13 },
    { name: 'bag', price: 7, amount: 4, discount: 84 },
    { name: 'cup', price: 3, amount: 6, discount: 10 },
    {name: 'magic wand', price: 33, amount: 37, discount: 1}
];
```

Then I created a service "ItemsService". Inside, I imported the variable "instock" and created this method:

```
import { inStock } from '../shared/instock';

  getInstock(): Instocktype[] {
    return inStock;
  }
```

then in my main app.component.ts file (Using dependency injection and all that), I created an "instock variable" like this:

```
  constructor(private is: ItemsService) {
    this.instock = this.is.getInstock();
  }
```

Then I created iterated over "instock" and using a `*ngFor` loop I created a table with as many rows as objects the "inStock" array has. and at the end of  each row I created a "delete" button, that deletes this row: like this:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of instock">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.amount}}</td>
        <td>{{item.price}}</td>
        <td>{{item.discount}}</td>
        <td><button mat-fab (click)="del(item)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then, after deleting all rows, if I console.log the "instock" variable in my main ts, it's empty (of course)

Where did it got empty, somewhere in the browser? in the RAM memory?

And my second question is this:

I put a `setTimeout` that fires after 5 seconds (time enough to delete all the rows). I'm trying to set again the now empty "instock" variable to the object array it originally had, by calling the service again, however, after doing this, and print it in console, it's still empty:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      /* Here I'm trying to fill again the variable with the object array.*/
      this.instock = this.is.getInstock();

      /* And here "console logging" it, but it's empty*/
      console.log(this.instock);

    }, 5000);

  }
```

My question is: if I'm calling the service again and setting the "instock" variable value to the object array that this service fetches, why does it continue to be empty?

Hope you can understand what I'm trying to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service returns you an array of objects and in **javascript** arrays and objects are reference type if you delete it from your main.ts it will also delete from the service file as well.

But if you want to re-assign the array to a new variable try to not to directly assign it.
You should return from the service method

```
 getInstock(): Instocktype[] {
    return inStock.slice(0);
  }
```

Comment: Now in that way you are not passing the reference or the same array you are now returning the new array instead